# How to insert a button to register a Datetime in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this MVC project of a time clock, and I want to do the following configuration on it: that the user just click on a button and register the "clock_in" and click on another button and register the "clock_out" below are the controller, the view and the model.If anyone can help me I will be very grateful

shifts_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @shift = Shift.new(shift_params.merge(user: current_user)) # quando criar ja mostra o id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shift.save
        format.html { redirect_to action: 'show', user_id: current_user, id: @shift, notice: 'Shift was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shift }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @shift.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

shift.rb

```
class Shift < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :clock_in, :clock_out, :user_id

  belongs_to :user

  def push_in
    self.clock_in = DateTime.now - 3.hours
  end

  def push_out
    self.clock_out = DateTime.now - 3.hours
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@shift, url: url, method: method )do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.time_field :push_in, value: f.object.push_in.strftime("%H:%M") %>
    <%= f.date_field :push_in %>
  </div>

    <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.time_field :push_out, value: f.object.push_in.strftime("%H:%M") %>
    <%= f.date_field :push_out %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <br/><%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is it that is not working with the current implementation? By the way, you are calling `f.object.push_in` in the `:push_out` field in `_form.html.erb`

Comment: Hi, Hector
the application is working, I want to implement an improvement. A button that saves the DateTime of its own database without the user choosing the day or time. As it is, the user can manipulate the information